# Sleep in goroutine with busy loop

Tags: go, sleep, goroutine

I have a switch statement inside a goroutine which handles the playback state of audio. The switch statement looks like this (it's controlled with channels)

```
PlaybackLoop:
        // Poll playback status and update current song
        select {
        case <-next:
            if current.next != nil {
                current = current.next
                break PlaybackLoop
            }
        case <-prev:
            if current.prev != nil {
                current = current.prev
            }
            break PlaybackLoop
        case <-done:
            return err
        default:
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
```

When no channels have inputs, the `default` case `sleep`s for 50 milliseconds. My justification for this is that I do not to refresh the UI or check media state etc (the stuff that happens in the `PlayBackLoop` before the switch statement) unnecessarily.

Is **sleeping** and appropriate way of making the goroutine more efficient? (by making less checks to the media player state?) Or is this assumptions wholly unfounded, and a simple `continue` would suffice?

Comment: No, sleeping is almost never a correct answer for any concurrency issues. Why do you need a `default` case in the switch? Can't you just wait for one of the receives?

Comment: No because the playback check above the switch statement for example plays the next song when the previous one ended, the sleep is supposed to cut down on that check

Comment: That means you're polling for an event rather than relying on a concurrency primitive. If there's really no way around polling, then yes, you don't want to create a busy loop and you should delay the polling slightly. In that case I would rather use a `time.Ticker` than the default case with Sleep.

Comment: This should definitely use a `Ticker` not a `Sleep`, and the "other code" that happens before the select should probably be inside the `Ticker`'s `case`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using calls to `time.Sleep` is never the right option for coordination of concurrent processes, and it is better to rely on synchronization primitives and the runtime to coordinate the concurrency whenever possible.

In this case it appears that you are polling for an event, and the sleep is there to prevent you from running a busy loop, which would only waste cpu and possibly starve other goroutines/threads of CPU.

If you cannot avoid the need to poll for an event, then you can improve this slightly by using a `time.Ticker` to make the polling interval more consistent.

```
    ticker := time.NewTicker(pollInterval)
    defer ticker.Stop()

PlaybackLoop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-next:
            if current.next != nil {
                current = current.next
                break PlaybackLoop
            }
        case <-prev:
            if current.prev != nil {
                current = current.prev
            }
            break PlaybackLoop
        case <-done:
            return err
        case <-ticker.C:
            pollForEvent()
        }
    }
```